# JavaScript Object storing only latest value in for loop

Tags: javascript, object, closures

I'm trying to store every value in an Object when my code parses the information from a database. However, it stores only the latest value. I tried console logging, and it's cycling though the for loop (meaning it outputs 1, 2, 3, 4, and not 4, 4, 4, 4 in the console). I've tried using 'let' instead of 'var' for the variable 'i' in the for loop and declaring the object in the for loop instead of outside the for loop, but to no avail. I think it has something to do with closures in JS, but I don't quite understand it yet.

Here's my code:

```js
var storage= {};
var reportRequest = {id 1: 1, id 2: 2, id 3: 3, id 4: 4};

        for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

            $.each(reportRequest.storage['id_' + i], function(id, info) {
                    storage[id] = info;
            });
        console.log(storage);
        }
```

It console logs '4, 4, 4, 4' (meaning the storage object holds only the value '4' for each cycle of the loop) when Object 'storage' is defined outside the for loop. When it is defined in the for loop, it'll console log '1', then '2', then '3', then '4'. Trying to get it to hold all four values at the same time.

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation and block braces?

Comment: Also [edit] the code to include a sample value for `reportRequest` so that we can reproduce the issue

Comment: @Bergi Done. I'm kinda new to JS, so please let me know if I'm missing something you need.

Comment: Still getting various errors when trying to run that.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining and initialising `storage` within the loop. Each time the loop executes, it will be overwritten. You effectively begin each iteration by removing the results of the previous iteration.

Try defining it outside of the loop, and only appending values within the loop:

```js
const storage = {};
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  $.each(reportRequest.responseJSON.metrics["id_" + i], function (id, info) {
    storage[id] = info;
  });
}
console.log(storage);
```

Note also you will need to make sure you refer to your `id` variable in the callback with the correct name (unless `identifier` is defined outside of the example provided).

Comment: `var` has no block scope. It's hoisted to the top of the execution context or script and in this case outside of the `for` loop. But the assignment part (`= {}`) will still be _in_ the loop

Comment: If I add storage to outside the loop, then it'll store only the last value '4' and console log only '4' instead of 1, 2, 3, 4. Trying to get the Object to store '1, 2, 3, 4,' instead of just '4'.

Comment: Could you share an example of this? Are you certain you are appending to the `storage` object and not overwriting it?

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely overwriting it, trying to append it though. Not sure how, even if I move the storage Object to outside the loop, it'll only keep and show the last value ('4') instead of "1, 2, 3, 4"

Comment: Could you share an example? I can't help you if I can't see your code.

Comment: Added a picture of the console log's output. The first 4 lines are the console.log(info) and the 5'th line is the console.log(storage), which is just outputting the value captured already, in this case, 1. Then it loops to 2, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry but the screenshot doesn't help. Can you please share your code with the suggested fixes, as well as the output as text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226298/discussion-between-secureentrepeneur-and-jimmy-sumshugar).

Answer (score 0):

define storage outside the loop and use the `identifier` in place of `id`

```
let storage = {};
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  $.each(reportRequest.responseJSON.metrics["id_" + i], function (identifier, info) {
    storage[identifier] = info;
  });
}
console.log(storage);
```

Comment: I fixed the identifier issue. Moving 'storage' to outside the for loop only console logs and stores only the latest value ('4') instead of storing and console logging '1, 2, 3, 4'

Comment: console.log(info);  inside each, I think you are storing 4 for all values.

Comment: It's storing 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 when I console.log (info) in the each statement. Trying to have it store "1, 2, 3, 4" all together, instead of having it be replaced each time the loop cycles through.